# How do I install Magento 2 on Mac OSX with Laravel Valet?

Tags: magento2, installation, php-7, nginx, localhost

## Question

How do I install and setup Magento with sample data to run locally?

### Background

I'm using Laravel Valet to manage my local development on Mac OS Sierra and want to do some work on a Magento 2 project.

#### Pre-requisites

- PHP Version 7.0.24
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for osx10.12
- Laravel Valet Version 2.0.4
- Composer Version 1.5.2
- mmv `brew install mmv`

#### Desired result

- Magento is available with admin / Admin123 at https://magento-2.dev

Comment: I have given step-by-step instructions to install Magento 2.2.3 on Valet+ which worked for me. http://ka.lpe.sh/2018/03/20/install-magento-2-2-3-valet-plus-macos/

Comment: My answer worked for me, if you care to share your answer as well I'm happy to upvote it :)

Comment: Good idea. I have shared my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have recently installed Magento 2 on Valet+ on my Mac. Here are the steps I have taken to successfully install it:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you don't have it on your Mac already
2. Install PHP 7
   `brew install homebrew/php/php71`
3. Install Composer `brew install homebrew/php/composer`
4. Install Valet+ by weprovide `composer global require weprovide/valet-plus`
5. Add export PATH in your bash profile `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`
6. Run valet install command `valet install`
7. Create sites directory where you will install Magento 2 `mkdir sites && cd sites`
8. Run command valet park to server sites `valet park`
9. Install Magento 2 `magerun2 install`
10. That's it! Open your newly installed site in browser by running command `valet open`

For detailed answer with output of each above-mentioned steps, I have already posted it on my blog. You can check it here: http://ka.lpe.sh/2018/03/20/install-magento-2-2-3-valet-plus-macos/

Also, credit to https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus for providing nice documentation.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

### 1. Complete the various set-up stages below.

### 2. Install magento using the command below.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 magento setup:install \
--admin-firstname="magento" \
--admin-lastname="admin" \
--admin-email="admin@email.com" \
--admin-user='admin' \
--admin-password="Admin123" \
--base-url="https://magento-2.dev" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-user="magento_2" \
--db-name="magento_2" \
--db-password="magento_2" \
--use-secure=1 \
--use-sample-data
```

### 3. Deploy front end assets.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

---

#### Magento directory / webroot setup

1. Download the [Magento CE 2.2 code with bundled sample data](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)
2. Unzip the archive to `~/www/magento-2`
3. Rename `*.ext.sample` files to `*.ext` `mmv -c \*.sample \#1`

---

#### Database setup

I use a custom Valet extension to create local databases.
copy the below valet Extension to `~/.valet/Extensions/db.php`

```
<?php
$app->command('db [name]', function ($name) {
    if (!$name) {
        warning('Please specify a database name');
        return;
    }

    $create_db_command = sprintf("mysql -uroot -e \"create database %s\"", $name);
    $create_user_command = sprintf("mysql -uroot -e \"create user '%s'@'localhost' identified by '%s'\"", $name, $name);
    $grant_privileges_command = sprintf("mysql -uroot -e \"grant all privileges on %s.* to '%s'@'localhost'\"", $name, $name);

    $commands = compact('create_db_command', 'create_user_command', 'grant_privileges_command');

    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        if ($error = CommandLine::run($command)) {
            warning($command);
            warning($error);
            return;
        }
    }
    info('The database '.$name.' has been created');
})->descriptions('Create a new database');
```

1. `valet db magento_2`

---

#### Valet site setup

1. `cd ~/www/magento-2 && valet link magento-2`
2. `valet secure magento-2`

---

#### Valet driver setup

Add a file containing the below driver code to `~/.valet/Drivers/Magento2ValetDriver.php`

```
<?php
class Magento2ValetDriver extends ValetDriver
{
    private $mageMode;

    public function serves($sitePath, $siteName, $uri)
    {
        return file_exists($sitePath . '/bin/magento') && file_exists($sitePath . '/pub/index.php');
    }

    public function isStaticFile($sitePath, $siteName, $uri)
    {
        $this->checkMageMode($sitePath);
        $route = parse_url(substr($uri, 1))['path'];
        $pub = '';
        if ('developer' === $this->mageMode) {
            $pub = 'pub/';
        }
        if (!$this->isPubDirectory($sitePath, $route, $pub)) {
            return false;
        }
        $magentoPackagePubDir = $sitePath;
        if ('developer' !== $this->mageMode) {
            $magentoPackagePubDir .= '/pub';
        }
        $file = $magentoPackagePubDir . '/' . $route;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            return $magentoPackagePubDir . $uri;
        }
        if (strpos($route, $pub . 'static/') === 0) {
            $route = preg_replace('#' . $pub . 'static/#', '', $route, 1);
            $_GET['resource'] = $route;
            include $magentoPackagePubDir . '/' . $pub . 'static.php';
            exit;
        }
        if (strpos($route, $pub . 'media/') === 0) {
            include $magentoPackagePubDir . '/' . $pub . 'get.php';
            exit;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function checkMageMode($sitePath)
    {
        if (null !== $this->mageMode) {
            // We have already figure out mode, no need to check it again
            return;
        }
        if (!file_exists($sitePath . '/index.php')) {
            $this->mageMode = 'production'; // Can't use developer mode without index.php in project root
            return;
        }
        $mageConfig = [];
        if (file_exists($sitePath . '/app/etc/env.php')) {
            $mageConfig = require $sitePath . '/app/etc/env.php';
        }
        if (array_key_exists('MAGE_MODE', $mageConfig)) {
            $this->mageMode = $mageConfig['MAGE_MODE'];
        }
    }

    private function isPubDirectory($sitePath, $route, $pub = '')
    {
        $sitePath .= '/pub/';
        $dirs = glob($sitePath . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        $dirs = str_replace($sitePath, '', $dirs);
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            if (strpos($route, $pub . $dir . '/') === 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function frontControllerPath($sitePath, $siteName, $uri)
    {
        $this->checkMageMode($sitePath);
        if ('developer' === $this->mageMode) {
            return $sitePath . '/index.php';
        }
        return $sitePath . '/pub/index.php';
    }
}
```

---

#### NGINX configuration.

1. Valet will have created a magento-2.dev nginx config file
2. Edit the `~/.valet/Nginx/magento-2.dev`
3. Add the location blocks in the `nginx.conf.sample` bundled with the Magento source code.

   ```
   upstream fastcgi_backend {
      server unix:/Users/user/.valet/valet.sock;
   }

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name magento-2.dev www.magento-2.dev *.magento-2.dev;
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }

   server {
       # SSL Setup
       listen 443 ssl http2;
       server_name magento-2.dev www.magento-2.dev *.magento-2.dev;
       charset utf-8;

       # SSL Certifcates
       ssl_certificate /Users/user/.valet/Certificates/magento-2.dev.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /Users/user/.valet/Certificates/magento-2.dev.key;

       # Logs
       access_log /Users/user/.valet/Log/nginx-access.log;
       error_log /Users/user/.valet/Log/nginx-error.log;

       # Magento Setup
       set $MAGE_ROOT /Users/user/www/magento-2;
       root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
       index index.php;
       autoindex off;
       error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
       add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

       location /41c270e4-5535-4daa-b23e-c269744c2f45/ {
           internal;
           alias /;
           try_files $uri $uri/;
       }

       location = /favicon.ico {
           access_log on;
           log_not_found off;
       }

       location = /robots.txt  {
           access_log off;
           log_not_found off;
       }

       # PHP entry point for setup application
       location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
           root $MAGE_ROOT;
           location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
               fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

               fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
               fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
               fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
               fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

               fastcgi_index  index.php;
               fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include        fastcgi_params;
           }

           location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
               deny all;
           }

           location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
               add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
           }
       }

       # PHP entry point for update application
       location ~* ^/update($|/) {
           root $MAGE_ROOT;

           location ~ ^/update/index.php {
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
               fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
               fastcgi_index  index.php;
               fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
               include        fastcgi_params;
           }

           # Deny everything but index.php
           location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
               deny all;
           }

           location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
               add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
           }
       }

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       }

       location /pub/ {
           location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
               deny all;
           }
           alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
       }

       location /static/ {
           # Uncomment the following line in production mode
           # expires max;

           # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
           location ~ ^/static/version {
               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
           }

           location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
               add_header Cache-Control "public";
               add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
               expires +1y;

               if (!-f $request_filename) {
                   rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
               }
           }
           location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
               add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
               add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
               expires    off;

               if (!-f $request_filename) {
                  rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
               }
           }
           if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
           }
           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
       }

       location /media/ {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

           location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
               deny all;
           }

           location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
               add_header Cache-Control "public";
               add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
               expires +1y;
               try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
           }
           location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
               add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
               add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
               expires    off;
               try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
           }
           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
       }

       location /media/customer/ {
           deny all;
       }

       location /media/downloadable/ {
           deny all;
       }

       location /media/import/ {
           deny all;
       }

       # PHP entry point for main application
       location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
           fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

           fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
           fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=18000";
           fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
           fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
       }

       gzip on;
       gzip_disable "msie6";

       gzip_comp_level 6;
       gzip_min_length 1100;
       gzip_buffers 16 8k;
       gzip_proxied any;
       gzip_types
           text/plain
           text/css
           text/js
           text/xml
           text/javascript
           application/javascript
           application/x-javascript
           application/json
           application/xml
           application/xml+rss
           image/svg+xml;
       gzip_vary on;

       # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
       location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
           deny all;
       }
   }
   ```

---

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Valet+ (https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus). This is based on Valet, but supports Magento 2 out of the box. And easy to install!